# Package gnome tweak tool is not available. package 'gnome-tweak-tool' has no installation candidate

Tags: gnome-tweak-tool

I can't find GNOME Tweak Tool in Ubuntu Software and it isn't found when I try to install it with APT

```
package 'gnome-tweak-tool' has no installation candidate
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 10):

In Ubuntu 18.04 and later GNOME Tweaks (*gnome-tweaks*) replaces the GNOME Tweak Tool (*gnome-tweak-tool*). GNOME Tweaks is a tool to adjust advanced configuration settings for GNOME. This is the same description as the description of the old GNOME Tweak Tool that it replaces. To install it open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt install gnome-tweaks
```